# Querying arrays in Redis with Predis

Tags: php, redis, predis, nosql

I want to to store and "SELECT" arrays in Redis with Predis, I entered data as follow:

```
$redis->hset("account_id_".$account_id, "access_time", time());
```

So I have this structure stored in redis

```
db0
    account_id_1
        access_time: 1400901850
        ...
        other values
    account_id_2
        access_time: 1400901862
        ...
        other values
    ...
    other_accounts
```

I want to select all accounts in a range of unix timestamps but I haven't find a way so far, I'm in doubt if the data structure is correct for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm in doubt if the data structure is correct for this purpose.

Your use of a hash is fine for storing the account data, but you need to make use of another data structure if you want better than O(N) lookup on the `access_time` field.  Namely, you should use a sorted set.

You should have an additional key in your database called `account:access_time` of type sorted set.  When an account is accessed, the following redis command should be run (with the appropriate variables filled in, of course):

```
ZADD account:access_time $access_time $account_id
```

Later on when you want to do a lookup based on access time, run the following:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE account:access_time $min_access_time $max_access_time
```

The above command will return a list of account IDs that you can then do your work on.